# MySQL query merge Duplicate Keys(2 tables)

Tags: mysql

I ask for your understanding because I can not speak English well.

There are two tables.
The primary key is time

```
A
A time | A_temperature
1027   | 30
1028   | 30
1030   | 60

B  
B time | B_temperature
1027   | 40
1029   | 50
1030   | 20
1031   | 59
```

I want the following results.

```
time | A_temperature | B_temperature
1027 | 30            | 40
1028 | 30            | NULL
1029 | NULL          | 50
1030 | 60            | 20
1031 | NULL          | 59
```

So I made the following query:

```
SELECT A.time, B.time, A_temperature, B_temperature
FROM A
JOIN B
    ON (B.time >= '1027' AND B.time <= '1031')
WHERE (A.time >= '1027' AND A.time <= '1031') 
GROUP BY A.time, B.time, A_temperature, B_temperature
```

After executing the above query, `A.time` and `B.time` are separated and the result is output.  I want to combine these at the same time.  If time is `null`, we want to put it in non-null time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need a full outer join here.  MySQL does not directly support a full outer join operator, but we can easily enough simulate one using a union of a left and right join.

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.time, B.time) AS time, A_temperature, B_temperature
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.time = B.time
UNION ALL
SELECT COALESCE(B.time, A.time), A_temperature, B_temperature
FROM A
RIGHT JOIN B ON A.time = B.time
WHERE A.time IS NULL
ORDER BY time;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that we take the `COALESCE` of the the times from each of the two tables.  This works, because it is guaranteed that one of the two tables will always have a non `NULL` time present (otherwise it wouldn't even be part of the join query).  But, it is *not* always guaranteed that both tables would always have a non `NULL` time.